# Which is the fastest DOM parser in python? Scrapy's built in selectors or lxml? Or some other parser

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, html-parsing, lxml

I have been using scrapy for 10-15 projects and trying out scrapy's parser and lxml parser with scrapy.

I wanted to find out which one is the best parser that can be used in python(In terms of parsing speed).

I tried to compare their performance by testing them to scrape product names for a category on a ecommerce site. but couldnt figure out the speed. 
1.I used lxml for parsing inside scrapy
2. I used scrapy's built in parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the lxml library's moto says

> "Programming with libxml2 is like the thrilling embrace of an exotic stranger. It seems to have the potential to fulfill your wildest dreams, but there's a nagging voice somewhere in your head warning you that you're about to get screwed in the worst way." (a quote by Mark Pilgrim)
> Mark Pilgrim was describing, in particular, the experience a Python programmer has when dealing with libxml2. The default Python bindings of libxml2 are fast, thrilling, powerful, and your code might fail in some horrible way that you really shouldn't have to worry about when writing Python code.
> **lxml combines the power of libxml2 with the ease of use of Python.**

Lib2xml in c is known to be the fastest parser.

And turns out scrapy uses parsel library which is a wrapper over lxml.

From scrapy [documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html)

> Scrapy Selectors is a thin wrapper around parsel library; the purpose of this wrapper is to provide better integration with Scrapy Response objects.
>
> parsel is a stand-alone web scraping library which can be used without Scrapy. It uses lxml library under the hood, and implements an easy API on top of lxml API. It means Scrapy selectors are very similar in speed and parsing accuracy to lxml.

So i guess i should use scrapy's selectors because it will be easier.